# Prove/Disprove: $\forall u\in V: \langle v,u \rangle = \langle w,u \rangle \implies v=w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Prove/Disprove: $\forall u\in V: \langle v,u \rangle = \langle w,u \rangle \implies v=w$.

I want to say "Yes", but couldn't formulate my intuition into a proof.

How to prove it?

Comment: It seems from your satisfaction with the answer below that the inner product is assumed nondegenerate.  If so, can you add that to the statement of the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "nondegenerate". That's the only information I've been given.

Comment: There are examples of inner product spaces where $\left<v,u\right>=0$ for all $u$ but $v\neq 0$.  But if you're not familiar with that term, you're probably supposed to assume that $(\forall u \in V \left<v,u\right>=0)\implies v=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall u\in V: \langle v,u \rangle = \langle w,u \rangle \implies \forall u\in V: \langle v-w,u \rangle =0$. Now put $u=v-w$ to get $\langle v-w,v-w \rangle = 0 \implies v-w=0\implies v=w$

Comment: Oh nice, I tried something similar actually! :)

Comment: @AlonAlon You are most welcome

Comment: But wait a minute, You chose a **specific** $u$. Why is it proving for every $u$?

Comment: Nothing to prove here for every u. A condition is given which is true for every u. You have to prove another result using this condition.So you are free to use any u to prove v=w. A special u is helpful to prove so.

Comment: I see now. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome